# Gradle checkstyleTest fails "CheckstyleException: Property 'allowMissingPropertyJavadoc' does not exist"

Tags: gradle, checkstyle

I get this error while running checkstyle on my custom test configuration - functionalTest.

Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: cannot initialize module TreeWalker - cannot initialize module JavadocMethod - Property 'allowMissingPropertyJavadoc' does not exist, please check the documentation
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.setupChild(Checker.java:477)
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AutomaticBean.configure(AutomaticBean.java:198)
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ant.CheckstyleAntTask.createRootModule(CheckstyleAntTask.java:412)
        ... 117 more
Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: cannot initialize module JavadocMethod - Property 'allowMissingPropertyJavadoc' does not exist, please check the documentation
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.TreeWalker.setupChild(TreeWalker.java:136)
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AutomaticBean.configure(AutomaticBean.java:198)
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.setupChild(Checker.java:472)
        ... 119 more
Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: Property 'allowMissingPropertyJavadoc' does not exist, please check the documentation
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AutomaticBean.tryCopyProperty(AutomaticBean.java:223)
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AutomaticBean.configure(AutomaticBean.java:191)
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.TreeWalker.setupChild(TreeWalker.java:131)
        ... 121 more

I see this field is set to true, in checkstyle.xml,

but I still get this error.

Comment: Which version of Checkstyle are you using?

Answer (score 13):

> Property 'allowMissingPropertyJavadoc' does not exist

https://checkstyle.org/releasenotes.html#Release_8.25

The property was removed in 8.25 as the functionality was moved to a new check, `MissingJavadocMethodCheck`, in 8.20. Since it was moved, the original check just kept the property to not break configuration and be deprecated. It was now removed.

I suggest you add `MissingJavadocMethodCheck` to continue the same behavior as before.
for example：

```
<module name="MissingJavadocMethodCheck">
  <property name="allowMissingPropertyJavadoc" value="true"/>
</module>
```

Comment: The issue is fixed. <br/> The new check - MissingJavadocCheck is specifically meant for the missing doc tags. As I am also using other functionality from JavadocMethodCheck, I sticked to JavadocMethodCheck but removed the unused->deprecated-> removed properties allowMissingPropertyJavadoc and minLineCount.     <br/>  Isn't there something called backward compatibility, I would have rather preferred to leave the existing ones as it is and create two new checks.<br/> Accepting this answer as it pointed me to the root cause.

Comment: You can have the same behavior as before just by adding `MissingJavadocCheck`. It has similar properties that were removed from `JavadocMethodCheck`.